# Running time complexity of bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was looking at the bubble sort algorithim in wiki, it seems that the worst case is `o(n2)`.

Let's take an `array size` of n.

```
int a = [1,2,3,4,5.....n]
```

For any n elements, the total number of comparisons, therefore, is `(n - 1) + (n - 2)...(2) + (1) = n(n - 1)/2 or O(n2)`.

Can anyone explain me how is `n(n-1)/2` equals `o(n2)`. I am not able to understand on how they came to a conclusion that the worst case analsysis of this algorithim is `o(n2)`

Comment: `n(n-1)/2` = `n^2/2 - n/2` = `O(n^2)` ... the Big O operator is looking at the most significant term in the expression, ignoring constants and lesser terms.

Comment: It's not o(n^2), since f(n)/n^2 -> 1/2 as n -> infinity.

Comment: There is a difference between o(n^2) and O(n^2).  The capitalization is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are looking at the case when N is getting closer to infinity. So `n(n-1)/2` would be practically the same as `n*n/2` or `n^2 / 2`.

And since they are only looking at how much does the time (which is required for it to run) increase as N increases that means that constants are irrelevant. In this case when N doubles the algorithm takes 4 times longer to execute. So we end up with `n^2` or `O(n^2)`.